# Reading textfile line by line and put in object array

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, line

I have to make an EPG app using java, but I am kind of new in programming and it's due tomorrow and it's still not working properly.

I have a question about a small part: I have to read the programs from a text file. Each line contains multiple things, the channel, the title of the program, a subtitle, a category, etcetera.

I have to make sure that I can read the separate parts of each line, but it's not really working, it's only printing the parts from the first line.

I am trying, but I can't find why it's not printing all the parts from all the lines in stead of printing only the parts from the first line. Here's the code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newFileReader(filepath));

while (true) {
String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
}

String[] parts = line.split("\\|", -1);
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
System.out.println(parts[i]);

}
reader.close();
```

Does anybody know how to get all the lines in stead of only the first?

Thank you!

Comment: You're missing a close brace; where does your while-statement actually end?

Comment: @azurefrog I believe the brace is only for the break. I proposed an edit already.

Comment: @Maxr1998 That's a reasonable guess, but still only a guess.  Given the lack of indentation, until the OP clarifies the code, it's difficult to know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

readLine() only reads one line, so you need to loop it, as you said.
BUT with reading to the String inside of the while loop you always overwrite that String.
You would need to declare the String above the while loop that you can access it from outside, too.

BTW, it seems that your braces for the if don't match.

Anyway, I'd fill the information into an ArrayList, look below:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String content;

// readLine() and close() may throw errors, so they require you to catch it…
try {
    while ((content = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       list.add(content);
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // This just prints the error log to the console if something goes wrong
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Now proceed with your list, e.g. retrieve first item and split
String[] parts = list.get(0).split("\\|", -1);

// You can simplify the for loop like this,
// you call this for each:
for (String s : parts) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use apache commons lib

```
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file);
```

Comment: Isn't that an overkill for his particular case? Also, he is new to programming, so he won't/shouldn't use libs already.

Comment: ok, maybe I have gone too far with previous code. I believe that showing an alternative is good way.

Comment: But he still would have to use a lib. Anyway, +1 for other method.

Comment: Yes indeed, from my experience when I was beginner I was very often doing something that already is done.

Answer (score 0):

As ArrayList is Dynamic,try,

```
private static List<String> readFile(String filepath) {
String line = null;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        list.add(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return list;
```

}